# nodejs file in parent directory

Tags: javascript, filesystems, fs

(NODEJS)
how do I access a file in the parent folder?
consider I have the following setup

```js
|Data.json
|-->Folder1
|      DataParser.js
```

how, in `dataparser.js` would i get `data.json`
(using `fs`)

Comment: What have you tried with fs so far?

Answer (score 0):

closed. found an answer:

```
var r = (__dirname.split("\\")).map((e, i) => {
    //if(i > (__dirname.split("\\").length - 1)) {
        return e;
    //}
});
//const dat = require(r.join("\\") + "data.json");
var dat = fs.readFileSync(r.join("\\") + "data.json");
```

I was forced to rename it to the name of the folder + data.json, though.